# Elixir: find the key for the list of lowest length, in a map of lists

Tags: elixir

What is an efficient way to find the key associated with the list of minimum length, in a map of lists in Elixir. Let's say I have:

```
z = %{a: [1, 2, 3], b: [4, 5], c: [6, 7, 8, 9]}
```

I know I can do:

```
Enum.map z, fn {k, v} -> length(v) end
```

which will give me:

```
[3, 2, 4]
```

But what I really need is just the answer, namely the key associated with the minimum value 2, which of course is :b.

I will be running this on dynamic map of lists approximately every second so I'd like it to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: What if multiple lists have equal minimum value?

Comment: @KevinJohnson then I am ambivalent between the lists of equal minimum value, but I still need a choice of only one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer simplicity over performance unless absolutely necessary, so here's how I would do it, if performance was less of a concern:

```
map
|> Enum.min_by(fn {_k, v} -> length(v) end)
|> elem(0)
```

Adding to the benchmark by @Dogbert reveals that this is ~1.5x slower with an avg. 90µs/iteration on my machine. That's still plenty of headroom to run it every second.

Comment: Yeah, I'd use this over mine or @mudasobwa's answer unless saving those microseconds is _really_ important.

Comment: Amazingly, and I am running this on an Arm architecture machine so that may make a difference, but this is at least 2x faster than any of the other 2 answers. Therefore in conjunction with its beautiful simplicity, you get the win. (For the other answers, I do appreciate the fact that fold and reduce were nicely demonstrated).

Comment: @ThomasBrowne nice to hear, that definitely teaches us something about always taking benchmarks with a grain of salt! However, skimming through the Elixir source code reveals that `min_by` internally just uses `reduce`, so I'm quite confused that this is faster than the other solutions. Out of curiosity: what are typical map and list sizes in your use case?

Comment: Actually my use case is usually a fairly small number of lists (up to 20 maximum) but the number of elements in each list can be large (between 2000 and 3000). I have tried both my use case, and the map generator from @dogbert, which seems to create 1000 small lists, and in both cases it seems that yours is faster. My use case is more like this: map = Enum.into(Enum.map(1..10, fn x -> {x, Enum.to_list(1..(2000 + :rand.uniform(1000)))} end), %{})

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for speed, `:maps.fold` would usually be a tiny bit faster than `Enum.reduce`. Here's an implementation which runs ~10% faster than @mudasobwa's implementation:

```
:maps.fold(
  fn k, v, {_, min} = acc ->
    l = length(v)
    if min == 0 || l < min, do: {k, l}, else: acc
  end,
  {nil, 0},
  map
)
|> elem(0)
```

Benchmark code:

```
map = for(key <- 1..1000, into: %{}, do: {key, Enum.random([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]])})

Benchee.run(%{
  "mudasobwa" => fn ->
    Enum.reduce(map, {nil, 0}, fn
      {k, v}, {_, len} when len == 0 or len > length(v) -> {k, length(v)}
      _, acc -> acc
    end)
    |> elem(0)
  end,
  "dogbert" => fn ->
    :maps.fold(
      fn k, v, {_, min} = acc ->
        l = length(v)
        if min == 0 || l < min, do: {k, l}, else: acc
      end,
      {nil, 0},
      map
    )
    |> elem(0)
  end
})
```

Output:

```
Name                ips        average  deviation         median         99th %
dogbert         12.36 K       80.90 μs    ±25.05%          73 μs      146.20 μs
mudasobwa       11.14 K       89.81 μs    ±34.32%          80 μs         185 μs

Comparison:
dogbert         12.36 K
mudasobwa       11.14 K - 1.11x slower
```

Comment: Also deviation 25% suggests not to take 10% of difference too serious.

Comment: How did you do the actual benchmarking? Is it built into iex?

Comment: @ThomasBrowne I used https://github.com/PragTob/benchee. It's not built in.

Comment: @Dogbert nice one. Now is there a "quick and dirty" way to import this (or generally, any module) into an iex session without starting a new project and putting it into mix.exs?

Comment: @ThomasBrowne Not really. What I do is: clone benchee, `cd` into it, copy the code into `foo.exs`, and run `mix run foo.exs`.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to do anything in Elixir is to [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3):

```rb
Enum.reduce(z, {nil, 0}, fn
  {k, v}, {_, len} when len == 0 or len > length(v) -> {k, length(v)}
   _, acc -> acc
end)

#⇒ {:b, 2}
```

To get `:b` only, pattern match the result:

```rb
{key, _} = ⇑the above⇑
```

or (worse) pipe to `|> Tuple.to_list() |> List.first`.

Here we update the accumulator if:

- we just started and the saved value is empty, or
- the new length is less than the old one.

Comment: @ThomasBrowne `first`, but avoid using it. Use match as described.

Comment: `|> Tuple.to_list() |> List.first()` is just `|> elem(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wishes to repeat @Dogbert's benchmark, including the answer of Patrick Oscity:

```
map = for(key <- 1..1000, into: %{}, do: {key, Enum.random([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]])})

Benchee.run(%{
  "mudasobwa" => fn ->
    Enum.reduce(map, {nil, 0}, fn
      {k, v}, {_, len} when len == 0 or len > length(v) -> {k, length(v)}
      _, acc -> acc
    end)
    |> elem(0)
  end,
  "dogbert" => fn ->
    :maps.fold(
      fn k, v, {_, min} = acc ->
        l = length(v)
        if min == 0 || l < min, do: {k, l}, else: acc
      end,
      {nil, 0},
      map
    )
    |> elem(0)
    end,
  "oscity" => fn ->
        map
        |> Enum.min_by(fn {_k, v} -> length(v) end)
        |> elem(0)
    end
})
```

My results on an Nvidia TX2 (64-bit ARM):

```
Name                ips        average  deviation         median         99th %

    oscity           252.78        3.96 ms     ±3.01%        3.92 ms        4.38 ms
    mudasobwa         80.66       12.40 ms     ±1.61%       12.37 ms       13.15 ms
    dogbert           32.90       30.39 ms     ±0.90%       30.32 ms       31.27 ms
```

Benchee code is here:

https://hex.pm/packages/benchee

ie just add 
`{:benchee, "~> 0.12.1"}` 
under deps in mix.exs.